# How to keyframe color ramp elements using python script

Tags: python, animation, scripting, node-editor, keyframes

I am currently having a problem where I am unable to use a python script to keyframe a color ramps position and color value.

Here is the code which I have tried to use
[image: The lines which are problematic, I have also added the console to help debug]

I went through two methods attempting to keyframe the position value. My first method is in line 651 which was attempted by selecting an active object which has the respective material. A second method line 652 I tried to access material data directly but doing so results in an attribute error.

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keyframe_insert'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

I have been through the blender documentation to find the correct method to control these values, I have additionally tried to follow the blender DataAPI path to see what I am doing wrong but cannot figure it out.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please add code as text, not as screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: I have figured it out with corrected code below.

`bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Cube']`

`--break--`

`bpy.data.materials["CubeMaterial"].node_tree.nodes["testRamp"].color_ramp.elements[0].keyframe_insert(data_path="position", frame= index)`

I brought the position into the data path and made the keyframe insert after the element selection.

Comment: Hi and welcome Matt. If you found a solution, please write it on the answers section so 
that other users with a similar question can learn from your 
experience. Read:
[Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)